# Easy Bash if-else

Tags: bash

OK, I can’t get this to work for some reason:

```
if /etc/mysql/my.cfn exist
then goto end;
else bash install.sh;

end exit;;
```

Comment: should be `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a relatively literal translation:

```
if [ -e /etc/mysql/my.cfn ]; then
    exit # Note: bash does not have a goto command
else
    bash install.sh
fi
```

Or, eliminate the irrelevant then condition, and invert the test:

```
if [ ! -e /etc/mysql/my.cfn ]; then
    bash install.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

Check for non-existence and run `install.sh` if true.

```
[[ ! -e /etc/mysql/my.cfn ]] && bash install.sh
```

Comment: for some reason this didnt work even if file exist, still ran script.

Comment: @jmituzas: what version of Bash then? The `[[` and `]]` are Bash intrinsics, so it depends entirely on Bash. For `[` there are usually binaries of that name that allow to use that syntax in any shell.

Answer (score 5):

The `:` command in bash with no arguments is a no-op, so you can use that in an if-body if you need to do nothing.

```
if something; then
    :
else
    do something else
fi
```

Of course, you'd normally want to write that as:

```
if ! something; then
    do something else
fi
```

or

```
something || do something else
```

Answer (score 4):

Your four lines in one line of Bash:

```
[[ -e /etc/mysql/my.cfn ]] && exit || bash install.sh
```

Did you mean my.**cnf** ?

Comment: Fewer lines of code are only better when you're doing one thing per line.

Comment: Doesn't the full `[[..]] && .. || ..` test structure do at least two things by definition? If it's short and readable, it's OK on one line.

Comment: Indeed it does do multiple things by definition, which is my point. It makes the code harder to maintain.

Comment: `[[..]] && .. || ..` can also have unintended behavior: if the && command fails, it'll execute the || command as well (in this particular case I don't know how `exit` could fail, so it's probably safe).

Answer (score 1):

(One) correct syntax is:

```
if [[ expression ]]; then
  command
else
  command
fi
```

The traditional style would be:

```
if test -f filename; then
  command
fi
```